# Show algebraically that the graph of $y=x^2 + kx - 2$ will cut the $x$-axis twice for all values of $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, quadratics

A quadratics question.

> Show algebraically that the graph of $y=x^2 + kx - 2$ will cut the $x$-axis twice for all values of $k.$

I recently asked a similar question, but this problem seems broader in scope.

Comment: $k$ here being any real number?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Right.

Comment: Show that the discriminant is strictly positive

Comment: @DavidQuinn Ah, so the two distinct roots proof.

Comment: If the $a$ and $c$ values have different signs (and are nonzero, as they are in this case) there will always be $2$ real solutions. This can be verified by the discriminant of the quadratic formula (showing it is strictly positive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the quadratic function, with a= 1, b= k, and c= -2.

There's three different outcomes for a quadratic:

${b^2-4ac}\gt 0 \rightarrow$ we get two solutions, which means we have two x-intercepts.

${b^2-4ac}=0 \rightarrow$ we get one solution, which means we have one x-intercept

${b^2-4ac}\lt 0 \rightarrow$ no real solutions, which means no x-intercepts. You can think of the parabola of the axis being above the x-axis if it opens upwards, or below the x-axis if it opens downwards.

Answer (score 0):

We are basically attempting to show that

$$ y = x^2 +kx - 2$$

Equals 0, for exactly two, distinct x, for any choice of real number k. A trick here is to basically factor the expression, and show that the factors give rise to distinct roots.

So we want to find an $a,b$ such that

$$ (x-a)(x-b) = x^2 + kx - 2$$

And show that regardless of the $k$, $a \ne b$.

This amounts to solving

$$ x^2 + kx - 2 = 0 \rightarrow x = \frac{-k \pm \sqrt{k^2+8}}{2}$$

And from here we let $a = \frac{-k + \sqrt{k^2 + 8}}{2}$, $b = \frac{-k - \sqrt{k^2 + 8}}{2}$.

now what is left to be shown is that, for ANY choice of k

$$\frac{-k + \sqrt{k^2 + 8}}{2} \ne \frac{-k - \sqrt{k^2 + 8}}{2} $$

Of course that is simply checking that

$$ -k + \sqrt{k^2 + 8}\ne -k - \sqrt{k^2 + 8}$$

And more importantly that:

$$ \sqrt{k^2 + 8}\ne- \sqrt{k^2 + 8} $$

Observe that the only time these are equal is if $k^2 = -8 \rightarrow k = \pm i 2\sqrt{2}$, but we already restricted our attention to $k$ being a REAL number, so we then can safely conclude that these two expression are never EQUAL.

and therefore, this quadratic ALWAYS has distinct roots.

And thus, it touches the x-axis exactly two times regardless of $k$.

---

@Joanpemo, points out rightly,

that while we have showing if $k$ is REAL that the roots are distinct, what have yet to show is that the ROOTs themselves are REAL too (otherwise the question of intersecting with the x-axis is pointless to begin with).

So to show

$$ \frac{-k \pm \sqrt{k^2+8}}{2}  $$

is real, we need to show

$$ -k \pm \sqrt{k^2+8} $$

is real, which reduces to showing that

$$ \sqrt{k^2 + 8}$$

is real, this follows from the fact that $k^2 > 0$ since $k$ is real, and thus this expression is always the square root of a positive number (which is well defined). So we conclude the roots themselves do lie on the real x-axis.

Comment: With all due respect this is too long and cumbersome, and at the end what we´re interesed in is whether the discriminant $\;k^2+8>0\;$ for all values of $\;k\in\Bbb R\;$ , which is trivially true...and this is *the only thing* we need and the one that wasn't addressed here.

Comment: In one sense we are, but why does that discrimjnant need to be positive, what does that concretely have to do with it intersecting with the axis. I haven't addressed discrimjnant a directly here because they are unnecessary. One can just use the most elementary of skills, and this is long, merely because I don't know what command my reader has over algebra. Better to give them something that spells out details, than have them clawing at me for explanations on steps. And ultimately they don't have to accept this answer, or even upvote it

Comment: Thank you. I think it is the most basic and elementary fact when learning about solutions of quadratic equations that there are two different *real* solutions iff the discriminant is positive. You **do need this**, whether you address explicitly it or you don't (and you didn't), otherwise it is always open the question whether the expression $\;\sqrt{k^2+8}\;$ is real or not...

Comment: In some sense this is a weaker piece, of the full proof that positive discriminants give rise to 2 distinct real roots. And that is different than what other answers give, and helpful, if the OP doesn't know why that is true but is being told to believe it. That said, anyone can upvote it/other answers. And the OP will accept whatever was truly useful to them

Comment: The proof of inequality and reduction to imaginary numbers, is what I refer to when stating "weaker piece ... That positive discriminants give rise to 2 distinct real roots"

Comment: Thank you, but I honestly have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense, quote me and attack it for being unclear, I will happily respond as it only helps every other person than arrives at this thread

Comment: You **must** prove *first* that the discriminant is non-negative otherwise the quadratic has no real solutions. This much you didn't do. What "proof of inequality and reduction to imaginary numbers" means is beyond my comprehension, and also what it has to do with all this.

Comment: This I cannot agree with, the OP has requested a proof that his/her Quadratic intersects the x-axis twice, meaning that it has two distinct real zeroes. Having a proof where we explicitly show the discriminant is positive is ONE but not the only way to prove this. What I have done is as follows: reduced the intersection of x-axis to finding two distinct zeroes, then used the quadratic formula to compute those two zeroes, then shown the only time when the two zeroes are EQUAL to each other is if $k$ is not a real number, thus it follows that if $k$ is a real number, the two zeroes-

Comment: must unequal, and therefore the quadratic intersect the x-axis twice

Comment: Proof of inequality and reduction to imaginary numbers, was my poorly worded reference to the part of the proof where I show inequality between the two roots. "Observe that the only time these are equal is if k^2 = ..." in my proof is the spot specifically.

Comment: Ok, this cannot continue as you, apparently, refuse to understand what I am trying to tell you. For the final time: **you must first prove there exists at least one solution to begin with**. Without this you haven't proved anything.

Comment: Okay I now see exactly what you are referring to, and agree with your sentiment. Thank you for being patient with me. i will add it to the end.

Answer (score -1):

for graph Y = x^2 + Kx -2 to cut x - axis y coordinate must be zero thus,

```
x^2 + Kx -2 = 0
```

Now for this equation for solution to be finitly 2 , b^2 - 4ac > 0.

here b = K , a = 1 and c = -2.

for every value of K , b^2 - 4ac will be greater than zero.

for example k = 0 => (0)^2 - 4(1)(-2) = 8

for k = -1 => (-1)^2 - 4(1)(-2) = 9

hence for all value of K it will be greater than zero so now we can find the solution of an equation.

Comment: "...for solution to be finite.."?

Comment: finite in the sense 2

Comment: What is "finite in the sense 2"??

Comment: I don't believe you are arguing on a finite word. In a quadratic with power 2 you can have 2 **finite** solutions. don't bother about finite read the answer if it is wrong than argue.

Comment: @Vishai Thank you. I think your answer isn't even wrong. It just doesn't make much sense, with all due respect: you "explain" that "for this equation to be finite 2 (??)" ...whatever. This deosn't make any sense unless you first explain what it means. To write "finite solutions" is, at least , misleading: there do *not* exist "infinite solutions" for a quadratic over any field, and finally: a quadratic (in one variable as is the case here) is **always** with power two as the maximal power of the variable, otherwise it is *not* a "quadratic".